# Express JS match route without handling

Tags: node.js, express

Given an instance of a Express JS app or router, is it possible to match a request against the apps configured routes and receive a object that describes the route as registered with the app?

For instance, if a request for `/users/1` were to be handled by the application, would it be possible for the `app`/`router` instance to programatically check if the app has a route that would satisfy this request given the URI and HTTP method?

Desirable sudo(ish) code:

```js
const app = express();

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    const handler = app.match(req);
    // {
    //     'method': 'GET',
    //     'path': '/user/:id', <--- mainly looking for this
    //     'handler': <function reference>
    // }
    next();
});

app.get('/user/:id', (req, res, next) => {
    // fetch the user and do something with it
});

...
```

Comment: so you don't want to handle requests? you only want to match them with patterns?

Comment: @RamiJarrar we do want to handle requests, however it is beneficial for our use case to be able to determine if the request would be handled prior to continuing down the middleware chain/stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there are no publicly documented Express router endpoints that provide the behavior you are describing based on its [`4.x` Documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#router).

However, you could implement this yourself by creating a custom regular expression validator to check if the `req.path` string matches any defined path. The downside to this is that you would have to maintain that list separately from what is registered to Express, which might prove to be difficult to maintain.

You may be able to root through the internals of the `app` object to get the functionality you need, but note the instability of that approach will mean your solution could potentially be broken by non-major updates to Express.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Perhaps I will add a issue to Express to request the functionality.

Comment: I've gone ahead and opened a issue on the ExpresJS github: https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/3977#issue-452089075